# How to query the jsonb path of the given nested json data which shows expense details with name of customer

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

```json
[
  {
    "WHO": "Joe",
    "WEEK": [
      {
        "NUMBER": 3,
        "EXPENSE": [
          {
            "WHAT": "Beer",
            "AMOUNT": 18.00
          },
          {
            "WHAT": "Food",
            "AMOUNT": 12.00
          },
          {
            "WHAT": "Food",
            "AMOUNT": 19.00
          },
          {
            "WHAT": "Car",
            "AMOUNT": 20.00
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "NUMBER": 4,
        "EXPENSE": [
          {
            "WHAT": "Beer",
            "AMOUNT": 19.00
          },
          {
            "WHAT": "Beer",
            "AMOUNT": 16.00
          },
          {
            "WHAT": "Food",
            "AMOUNT": 17.00
          },
          {
            "WHAT": "Food",
            "AMOUNT": 17.00
          },
          {
            "WHAT": "Beer",
            "AMOUNT": 14.00
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "NUMBER": 5,
        "EXPENSE": [
          {
            "WHAT": "Beer",
            "AMOUNT": 14.00
          },
          {
            "WHAT": "Food",
            "AMOUNT": 12.00
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "WHO": "Beth",
    "WEEK": [
      {
        "NUMBER": 3,
        "EXPENSE": [
          {
            "WHAT": "Beer",
            "AMOUNT": 16.00
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "NUMBER": 4,
        "EXPENSE": [
          {
            "WHAT": "Food",
            "AMOUNT": 17.00
          },
          {
            "WHAT": "Beer",
            "AMOUNT": 15.00
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "NUMBER": 5,
        "EXPENSE": [
          {
            "WHAT": "Food",
            "AMOUNT": 12.00
          },
          {
            "WHAT": "Beer",
            "AMOUNT": 20.00
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "WHO": "Janet",
    "WEEK": [
      {
        "NUMBER": 3,
        "EXPENSE": [
          {
            "WHAT": "Car",
            "AMOUNT": 19.00
          },
          {
            "WHAT": "Food",
            "AMOUNT": 18.00
          },
          {
            "WHAT": "Beer",
            "AMOUNT": 18.00
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "NUMBER": 4,
        "EXPENSE": [
          {
            "WHAT": "Car",
            "AMOUNT": 17.00
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "NUMBER": 5,
        "EXPENSE": [
          {
            "WHAT": "Beer",
            "AMOUNT": 14.00
          },
          {
            "WHAT": "Car",
            "AMOUNT": 12.00
          },
          {
            "WHAT": "Beer",
            "AMOUNT": 19.00
          },
          {
            "WHAT": "Food",
            "AMOUNT": 12.00
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: So what is the output you want? What problem does your current query have?

Comment: if i use this  SELECT jsonb_path_query(data,'$.WEEK[*]?(@.NUMBER >1).EXPENSE[*]?(@.AMOUNT > 15).WHAT') FROM EXPENSES;    it works but instead if i use  SELECT jsonb_path_query(data,'$.WHO[*]?(@.WHO =="Beth").EXPENSE[*]?(@.AMOUNT > 15).WHAT') FROM EXPENSES; it doesnot work.    what i need is the expenses of a perticular person who only.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.